# Sudoku solver - slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

Tags: python, numpy, sudoku

I am trying to write a solver for my Sudoku Solver but I am getting the following error when I ran my sudoku solver. I didn't understand what the problem is. I look other questions but could not fix the problem also.
Below is my code and the problem:

```
import numpy as np

class SolveSudoku(object):
    def __init__(self,grid):
        self.grid = grid

    def _check_row(self,digit,row):
        return digit not in self.grid[row,:]

    def _check_column(self,digit,column):
        return digit not in self.grid[:,column]

    def _check_box(self,digit,row,col):
        rc = (row/3)*3
        cc = (col/3)*3
        return digit not in self.grid[rc:rc+3,cc:cc+3]

    def _check_safe(self,digit,row,col):
        return self._check_box(digit,row,col) \
               and self._check_row(digit,row) \
               and self._check_column(digit,col)

    def _find_empty(self,stop):
        if 0 in self.grid:
            stop[0] = np.where(self.grid==0)[0][0]
            stop[1] = np.where(self.grid==0)[1][0]
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def _solve(self):
        stop = [0,0]
        if not self._find_empty(stop):
            return True
        for digit in np.arange(1,10):
            row = stop[0]
            col = stop[1]
            if self._check_safe(digit,row,col):
                self.grid[row,col] = digit
                if self._solve():
                    return True
                self.grid[row,col]=0
        return False

    def solve(self):
        if self._solve():
            return self.grid
        raise("Sudoku can not be solved")
```

---

```
File "solve.py", line 117, in <module>
        grid = sudoku.solve()
      File "C:\Users\Erke\.spyder-py3\SudokuSolver-master\sudoku.py", line 47, in solve
        if self._solve():
      File "C:\Users\Erke\.spyder-py3\SudokuSolver-master\sudoku.py", line 39, in _solve
        if self._check_safe(digit,row,col):
      File "C:\Users\Erke\.spyder-py3\SudokuSolver-master\sudoku.py", line 20, in _check_safe
        return self._check_box(digit,row,col) \
      File "C:\Users\Erke\.spyder-py3\SudokuSolver-master\sudoku.py", line 17, in _check_box
        return digit not in self.grid[rc:rc+3,cc:cc+3]
    TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Comment: On Python 3, `some_int / some_int` produces a float, not floor-division.

Comment: I am still have problems even I used // instead of / and downgraded my numpy to 1.11.2.

Comment: If you share a sample code that would generate the error it's probably easier to interpret.  Right now don't know what the `grid` is expecting.